# Remove double arrows from icon

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

Due to some unknown reason, all my files and folders have started to show double arrows on them. Please see pictures.
[image]

[image]

How do I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue arrows indicate which folders, sub-folders and files have been compressed on your computer. To remove the arrows, highlight the files with the blue arrows, right click them, then follow the pictures below:

Choose 'Properties' from the menu below

[image]

Click on 'General', then click on 'Advanced'

[image]

Uncheck 'Compress contents to save disk space' to get rid of the arrows

[image]

Select 'Apply changes to all folders, sub-folders and files'

[image]

Select 'OK'.

Select 'OK' again (If a box with a green bar appears, wait for it to disappear),  and the arrows will be gone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is identical to mine and you just added the images.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing against that, I just added images to allow more easy-to-follow instructions. I did not 'copy' you. I provided my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Those indicate that NTFS compression is enabled on the folders. I think any recent windows update compressed the files in home directory order to ensure free space on the disk. To remove that, right click the file and click properties, click advanced then uncheck Compress Contents to save disk space and then click OK.